# при работе с python в командной строке Windows выдает ошибку

Tags: python, windows

При работе с python в командной строке стало невозможно выполнить никакую команду, т.к. программа выдает сообщение об ошибке и закрывается.[image: при вводе команды print("Hi") работа Python прекращается]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить питон.

Comment: Несколько вопросов. В какую папку установлен пайтон? Какие у вас права на эту папку и на подпапки? Какая винда стоит?

Comment: @Александр, я уже переустанавливал его несколько раз. И поначалу он работает, а потом (после установления flask, например, или чего-то еще) начинает выдавать ошибку.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Windows 7, python лежит в папке C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python ограничений прав нет никаких и такая же проблема была если я ставил пайтон на диск C:\Python

Comment: При возникновении подобной ошибки откройте системный лог Administration - Event Log - Applications. И посмотрите что там в логах от пайтона написано. Из-за чего ему плохо стало.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Имя журнала:   Application
Источник:      Application Error
Дата:          20.03.2019 14:48:18
Код события:   1000
Категория задачи:(100)
Уровень:       Ошибка
Ключевые слова:Классический
Пользователь:  Н/Д
Компьютер:     1-com
Описание:
Имя сбойного приложения: python.exe, версия: 3.7.2150.1013, отметка времени: 0x5c200a7f
Имя сбойного модуля: ntdll.dll, версия: 6.1.7601.24387, отметка времени 0x5c7f386b

 Это то, что нужно? Я в этом, честно говоря, не разбираюсь.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov (продолжение) ... Код исключения: 0xc0000374
Смещение ошибки: 0x000c3bd3
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x488
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d4df55db9a101d
Путь сбойного приложения: C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Код отчета: 1b8340cc-4b49-11e9-b94b-50465d8f1ef0

Comment: Удалите папку `.idlerc`, она лежит по пути `C:\Users\1\.idlerc` и попробуйте запустить пайтон ещё раз. Если не сработает, удалите эту папку ещё раз, если она была создана, запустите установщик пайтона и выберите в нём "Repair".

Comment: @RafaelOsipov ничего не помогает. Я даже переустановил пайтон, но он не хочет работать. Спасибо вам за поддержку!

Comment: А апдейты для семерки все стоят? Просто может быть несовместимость какая-то у последней сборки пайтона. Может статься она заточена уже под десятую винду. Как вариант, попробуйте поставить python 3.5.0 вот отсюда: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Python 3.5.0 работает. Попробую продолжить работу с ним. Спасибо большое, Rafael!

Comment: Если будет время и желание, попробуйте поднимать версию постепенно, пока не найдете максимально работающую версию с семеркой. Но это актуально, если вы используете нововведения в последних версиях пайтона. Если версия 3.5 вас устраивает, то ничего менять, естественно не надо. Рад был помочь.

Comment: Спасибо большое еще раз, Rafael! Дело в том, что поначалу версия 3.7 работала. Но потом перестала...